# how to pass an array with one element as a parameter of a GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, object

This code works if I pass an array with multiple elements to /submit. However if I pass an array with one element to /submit the array arr becomes an array of characters. How can I make this work?

```
app.use('/submit',(req,res)=>{
var arr= new Array()
arr.push(...req.query.array)
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

request.get(arr[i], function (error, response, body) {
...

}}}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing an array and not just a string that isn't in an array?

Comment: Why don't you just do `var arr = req.query.array;`? Is there a reason you need to make a copy? And if you want a copy, use `var arr = req.array.slice();`

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. Express checks whether there are multiple parameters with the same name. If there are, it puts them in an array, otherwise it makes it a single parameter.

Comment: This is my request localhost:3000/submit?array=www.google.com&array=www.amazon.com

Comment: Try giving your parameter a name that ends with `[]`. That should tell it to always put it in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter name needs to end with `[]` so that the server code knows to put the values into an array, even if there's only one instance.

```
localhost:3000/submit?array[]=www.google.com&array[]=www.amazon.com 
localhost:3000/submit?array[]=www.google.com
```